# java API wrapper for com.sun.jersey.spi.container.* and com.sum.jersey.core.* packages

Tags: java, jersey, sun

Are there any java API wrapper for com.sun.jersey.spi.container.* and com.sum.jersey.core.* packages?
As Classes in com.sun.* and sun.* packages are considered implementation details, and are not part of the Java API. They can cause problems when moving to new versions of Java because there is no backwards compatibility guarantee.

Comment: Where do you need to directly use those classes?

Comment: I am using those classes in jersey request filters